# MSQL: Join not working

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im asking this question again, because my last one was marked as duplicate, and i was advised to use FULL OUTER JOIN, which is **not possible in MYSQL!**

I'm having a table `user`

`ID | USERNAME | NAME | PASSWORD | PERMISSION |`

and a table `products`

`ID | NAME | DATE | USER | VALUE|`

The idea is to create a list in PHP which displays all users, with username, and full name, and the SUM of entries in `products` the made. If an User didn't made any entries, it should display none or 0.

Currently, I'm using a simple Join, but then only users will show up, that have made at least 1 entry. A newly created user is not visible

How is the exact query to solve this?

Please don't mark this question as duplicate, because it isn't, its about MYSQL and not SQL.

Comment: Why don't you use left join?

Comment: left join does also only display user which have made at least one entry. but i want all users.

Comment: Flip your left join. You want to left join `products` to `user`, not left join `users` to `product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT USERNAME, NAME, SUM(VALUE) as TOTAL
FROM user LEFT JOIN products ON user.ID=products.USER
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY USERNAME;
```